# Java getClass().getResource(string) not working on netbeans path

Tags: java, url

I have been trying to access a local file in my java project on my netbeans IDE using the
          getClass().getResources("/res/myfile.extension") 
but it doesn't seem to be working. I don't know what am doing wrong here but I need help. Please help me.

Comment: Try to put with the complete path like "C:/..."

Comment: Possible (recent) duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219224/why-does-class-getresource-keep-returning-null-although-there-is-a-resource-at

Comment: Try unzipping the jar file a check to see if the files exists. Where does res/myfile.extension reside within your project?

Comment: @Razib `getResourceAsStream()` works on relative URLs, not filenames.

Answer (score -1):

Your folder (/res) is probably in a different place than it `getClass().getResources` looking for.

I suggest watching what files you have available.
For example this way:

```
    List<String> files = null;
    try {
        files = IOUtils.readLines(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("./") );
System.out.println(files);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

IOUtils is from apache-commons:

```
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
```

Comment: Does `getResourceAsStream()` really return a directory listing for a directory